# Reporting all the matches in string matching by KMP

Tags: c, string-matching

I use the following KMP algorithm code for string matching. Its works fine to search a given pattern in the string.

```
/*
 * C Program to Implement the KMP Pattern Searching Algorithm  
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
       char string[100], matchcase[20], c;
       int i = 0, j = 0, index;

    printf("Declertion and Initialization done:\n");

      /*Scanning string*/
        printf("Enter string:");
        do
        {
            fflush(stdin);
            c = getchar();
            string[i++] = tolower(c);

        } while (c != '\n');

        string[i - 1] = '\0';
    printf("The string after scanning is:%s\n",string);
    printf("String length of string is: %d\n",strlen(string));

        /*Scanning substring*/
        printf("Enter substring: ");
        i = 0;
        do
        {
            fflush(stdin);
            c = getchar();
            matchcase[i++] = tolower(c);

        } while (c != '\n');

        matchcase[i - 1] = '\0';

        for (i = 0; i < strlen(string) - strlen(matchcase) + 1; i++)
        {
            index = i;

            if (string[i] == matchcase[j])
            {
                do
                {
                    i++;
                    j++;

                } while(j != strlen(matchcase) && string[i] == matchcase[j]);

                if (j == strlen(matchcase))
                {
                    printf("Match found from position %d to %d.\n", index + 1, i);
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    i = index + 1;
                    j = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("No substring match found in the string.\n");

        return 0;
    }
```

It searches the pattern successfully,giving the first match only,however ,i am interested to report all the matches. Thanks

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior.

Comment: I would do `string[i] = '\0';` instead of `i-1`

Comment: This "algorithm", as coded, is quite inefficient. The calls to `strlen` in the expression `i < strlen(string) - strlen(matchcase) + 1` are evaluated every loop iteration while these string lengths are invariant.

Comment: So add a loop. I fail to see the problem here. (Unless this is a one-off and a test to see if you are able to write the code, I'd suggest making the `find` a separate function. With that, adding the loop would become extremely trivial (even more so).)